# using Cloud Firestore in cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Function Documentation says

> // The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
>   const admin = require('firebase-admin');
>   admin.initializeApp();

I am using Cloud Firestore, not Realtime Database. How do I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `admin.firestore()` like for example:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = requi re('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


//Write a function that uses Firestore, e.g.: 

exports.anHttpCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

   admin.firestore().collection('XYZ').doc('ABC').set(....)
   .then(() => {
       res.send({ msg: 'Success' });
   })
   .catch(err => {....})

});
```